# Should I upgrade version in Manifest on code change, MS office js?

Tags: ms-word, office-js, manifest, versioning

When building MS Office add-ins with the office-js you can change the version of the app in the Manifest. But, as far as I can see the Manifest is just there to point to a website that has the information on how to run the add-in app. So, right now I am just pushing my changes to the website, and I never change the Manifest at all.

Do I need to upgrade the version number in the Manifest every time I push changes to the office add-in?

I am asking in general, but one reason I am wondering is that my users are experiencing cache issues, and issues with their security, that I am thinking might get resolved by upgrading the version every time - but then the user has to add the add-in from the store again every time, and it also gives me an extra step in my process.